# Принцип работы 

Tags: html

Писал всегда в тэге a ссылку на http:// или mailto: и всегда думал, что этим все и ограничивается. Но оказалось что писать в нем можно еще много всего, например magnet:

Так вот, что же можно писать в a href="" и как это работает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это [протоколы передачи данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) (на Вики не очень статья, но там ничего трудного и непонятного нет). Например: http(s), ftp, goopher, irc, xmpp, icq, market да и много других. Они могут быть любыми. Главное, чтобы была установлена программа, которая сможет работать с этим протоколом.